# Vagrant's Ubuntu 14.04 でのUbuntuユーザーパスワードは何でしょうか？

Tags: vagrant

Ubuntu 16.04だとxenial64/20161221.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile
に書かれているそうなんですが、
私の場合はtrusty64のUbuntu14.04を使っているのですが、vagrantfileには書いてありませんでした。教えてください。ちなみに調べたのは以下のフォルダのVagrantfileです。
ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20190429.0.1/virtualbox/Vagrantfile

Comment: `vagrant ssh`でゲストOSへのログインは出来ていますか？

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41337802

Answer (score 2):

ユーザ "ubuntu" にはパスワードは設定されていないようです。

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo grep ubuntu /etc/shadow
ubuntu:!:18153:0:99999:7:::
```

---

`vagrant ssh` コマンド実行時にパスワードを聞かれたのであれば、それは "vagrant" ユーザとログインしようとしています。つまり("ubuntu" ユーザでなく) "vagrant" ユーザのパスワードが必要です。
デフォルトのパスワードは "vagrant" でした([参考](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html#quot-vagrant-quot-user))。

"vagrant" ユーザでログインした後、`sudo passwd ubuntu` コマンドを実行することで "ubuntu" ユーザにパスワードを設定できます。